# WIFI & Data Connection Problem

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, mobile-data, motorola-moto-g2, file-sharing

I have just updated my Moto G2 to Lollipop 5.0.2. I am unable to share files over WiFi via any of these apps like Superbeam, Xender, Cshare.

Also while using data connection, I'm unable to see the symbol H, H+ or E. Why is it so?

Comment: You won't see your mobile data connection when on wifi because you are on wifi. You are only connected to one of them at a time, either mobile data, or wifi.

Answer (score -1):

Uncheck 3G option on the 1st SIM, and click on 3G option on 2nd SIM.